# Scrapyd project does not persist between Docker container runs

Tags: docker, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a Docker container running Ubuntu hosted on Windows 10 Pro. The Scrapy and Scrapyd packages have been installed in the container and all is well.  I added a project, Project A, to Scrapyd using scrapyd-deploy and all is still well. I can schedule Project A's spider using curl and the schedule.json API, and crawl till the cows come home.

The problem is that Project A does not persist between container runs. After the cows have come home, and stopping and running the Ubuntu container, Scrapyd contains 0 projects as evidenced by listprojects.json. I have tried commiting the container but the project does not persist.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please adjust your question to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Did you try any persistence methods on your container? Please share essential parts of your compose file / dockerfile so that we can try helping you.

Comment: @trust512 Thank you for the comment. I'm assuming that Scrapyd saves added projects to disk on the file system it is running on, at least it does on native Windows. I've started and stopped the Scrapyd server running on the Ubuntu container several times and the project persists. Can you suggest any "persistence methods" I can use on my container besides the Docker commit I mentioned?

Comment: Sure we can make it persistent, but you need to be more specific. How do your run your `scrapyd`?

Comment: I run it directly from bash'

Comment: Ok, but I mean do your run it like `docker run -it scrapyd` or somehow different?

Comment: Perhaps I'm making assumptions about Docker based on experience with Virtual Box.  Will Docker only persist data to the host?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171273/discussion-between-trust512-and-rstuppi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up a discussion from comments.

You have to mount the two paths from container into your host system in order to persist your data.

You define the mount like this:

```
$ docker run -it -v runtime-storage:/usr/src/app/runtime_storage -v results-storage:/usr/scr/app/results scrapyd-36
```

[docs ref](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes)

Comment: Maybe a stupid question on an old q&a: with regard to scrapyd, by `runtime_storage` and `results_storage` are you talking about the `eggs_dir` and `items_dir`? I'm really more concerned with what you call `runtime-storage` which I can't find referenced anywhere.

Comment: It's been a few yrs and so scrapyd has probably changed where/how it stores data - thus the confusion. Their docker hub page has improved greatly though, so I believe you will find the answer here https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick/scrapyd under the sample `docker-compose.yml` file :) hope it helps

Comment: I am on an older version of scrapyd, so the original question is more relevant to me than the current vimagick docker image.

Comment: The link is relevant to me: https://github.com/vimagick/dockerfiles/tree/a62429af3cdd1b996eb8ce77c02b9090bf03ec1c/scrapyd#docker-composeyml

Comment: cool, IIRC `runtime-storage` was only defined to keep the application data in one place (in case there's any time-consuming init to be done), though it wasn't of much relevance to the question. The important bit is the `results-storage`, is that not working for you? With the default config a simple `./data:/var/lib/scrapyd` should suffice completely and store stuff locally instead of in a volume.

Comment: Results are going in S3 buckets, so `results-storage` isn't a big deal. EFS will be where the`runtime-storage` lives. Still experimenting with my local Docker to get this right. Thanks for your help!